# Simple Analytics for a Website

Tags: asp.net, analytics

I have a web site that consists of several Aspx pages to apply for certain products. The visitor starts at Selection.aspx, visit as many pages as the products he selected then ends up with the summary page.

I want to know how many visitors visited the first page, how many of them reached the last page and how many of them left the site without reaching the last page (and at which page did they leave).

I am thinking of creating a simple database table that stores the IP of the visitor and the page he is visiting. The method to fill this table will be called at the Page_Load of each Aspx page. Are there better ways than this?

During my research I have read about Google Analytics and other Analytics tools, e.g. http://piwik.org/. Will these Analytics engines help me meet my requirements or should I use the home grown method? If yes, which Analytics tool do you recommend?

Comment: I use Google Analytics and I am very happy. They provide me what I need.

Comment: Not constructive at all, opinions on this topic vary too much to provide a definite answer, thus this doesn't belong here I'm afraid. Both approaches have pros and cons, you need to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As a user of both tools, then either of them will deliver what you need with only a few minutes setup.

The advantages of Piwik is that you own the data, and it is open source.  This means you can customise it as you wish, providing you the ability to get very tailored reports on your site activity.  That said, Piwik is PHP, so if you have an ASP background, this may not be such an advantage.

The downside of Piwik is that you need to host it and manage the database (unless you go for a hosted mysql solution like Amazon RDS).  You'll also a need a geoip database, since without one, Piwik uses the user agent Accept-Language to infer location.  The free MaxMind db is OK, but not as accurate or complete as Google's.

With Google, the reports are simple and intuitive and the real time analytics can give you great insight into how your site is being used at a single point in time.

The Google APIs are sufficient to extract your data to use elsewhere, and it can hook into other Google services like Webmaster Tool, Website Optimizer and Google Adwords. The downside is that Google own *and* use your analytics data.

Both Google Analytics and Piwik allow you to set up goals like User visits Page A, and then visits Page B etc.  They also both have tools to graphically show the flow and drop off, which would most likely satisfy your requirement of seeing how far users get in your process.

Unless you have a secondary use for your own analytics code, you'll probably be better off going for either of these and focusing your time and resources on the rest of your project.

Answer (score 2):

Further PassKit's answer it is worth expanding on conversion funnels. 
These conversion funnels will allow you to see funnel conversion rates and identify at what stage a visitors drops out of a funnel.

An example funnel might look like this:

1. Landing page
2. Product page
3. Sign up page
4. Payment page
5. Conversion page

Using this funnel we could see how many people reached the Conversion page, but also where visitors dropped out of this funnel.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest tool to implement analytics on your site, with decent reports, etc. is Google Analytics. You simply register, place the code snippet they provide in your pages, and in a few days you get back basic data. For your needs you can create a 'goals' to track percentages of how many visitors go through a series of pages, etc. It is fairly easy to set up.

However, you might be better off investigating your hosting provider or looking at your webserver logs (if hosting yourself). There are numerous tools out there to analyze these logs and they are much more detailed than Google Analytics will provide. The hosting provider I use has SmarterStats available, which provides very easy to read reports and excellent data about the visitors. The data is very detailed about each visitor.

Good luck!